# Units of measures and statistical models with F#

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

For a statistical model, if I want to use units of measure consistently, I need to encode somewhere the number of data I have.

```
type DataSet<[<Measure>] 'x, [<Measure>] 'y, [<Measure>] 'n>  = 
        DataSet of Matrixu<'n,'x> * Vectoru<'n,'y>
```

I can then define a function that merges 2 Dataset

```
static member (+) (a:DataSet<'x,'y,'n1>,b:DataSet<'x,'y,'n2>):DataSet<'x,'y,n>  = ...
```

But I want to be able to merge unknonw number of dataset of different sizes.
How do I define such a function ?

The naive ways fails because a sequence is only of 1 kind, so I'd need to statically define the size.

```
    static member merge (ar:DataSet<'x,'y, ??? > seq) : DataSet<'x,'y, 'n>  = 
        if seq.empty, etc...
        let   head = ar |> Seq.head
        let others = ar |> Seq.skip 1
        others |> Seq.fold (fun st el -> st + el) head
```

Or should I just add specific rules and not take care of the size of data.
That means adding custom dimension management in applicative code, which is dirty as well.. and kind of ruins the point of having clean dimensions in the first place !

Comment: What role does measure 'n take here? Is it the "number of data"? That does not sound like a unit of measure to me. Other question: in `static member (+)`, how is `n` in the return type related to `'n1` and `'n2`?

Comment: indeed, n would be the number of data. in a matrix n by m, that describes a 'type' of matrix...

Comment: in static +, we'd have n = n1 + n2 , (for a some + operation between types in bijection with natural numbers ) but I dont think it is enforceable, so i just let this dimension free.

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear to me, but I suspect that F#'s type system can't handle that type of operation, just like it can't give a meaningful unit-of-measure-aware signature to `pown`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are stretching the usage of units of measure. In my experience they work great for physics and similar (finance, I guess), but that's it. I don't believe they can handle sizes of static containers (eg n-by-m matrices).

Have you heard about dependent type systems and [F*](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/fstar/)? I've seen examples with fixed-size lists which indicate it might fit the job. It's still a research project at Microsoft, might not be suitable for commercial use.